# user-error: That register’s buffer no longer exists

Tags: bookmarks, registers

I saved point to register, closed buffer / restarted Emacs and got:

```
user-error: That register’s buffer no longer exists
```

I want Emacs to open file if necessary and go to point.

Answer (score 2):

I tried bookmarks and they survive buffer closing and Emacs reloading:

```
(info "Bookmarks (emacs)")
```

> “Bookmarks” are somewhat like registers in that they record positions
>   you can jump to.  Unlike registers, they have long names, and they
>   **persist automatically** from one Emacs session to the next.  The
>   prototypical use of bookmarks is to record where you were reading in
>   **various files**.

Even more! `~/.emacs.d/bookmarks`  keeps lines like:

```
(("wsl"
 (filename . "~/my/gtd/BLOG.rst")
 (front-context-string . "\nLegacy WSL was ")
 (rear-context-string . "larms.\n\nWSL\n===\n")
 (position . 1052073))
```

so Emacs is able to point cursor to the same position even if you edit surrounding (add/remove lines). See `bookmark-search-size`.